# How do I back up my rails database on the fly?

Tags: backup, heroku, sqlite

I have been looking for a way to back up my app's database which is hosted by heroku. It uses an sqlite database. What I am looking for is a way to add a button on my site which will allow me to download the database as an sqlite file.  I am sure there is some simple fix I am overlooking but it would be great if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Using SQlite on Heroku is really dangerous because as soon as the process completes, all your data will be lost. Is there a reason you are not using the free Postgres database that Heroku provides?

Comment: It was my first heroku app and my first rails app at the time. The point of the backup is so that I can migrate to postgres.  Also, the process has been restarted many times and I have not lost my data so I do not think you are right about that.

Comment: SQLite can be in-memory, or on disk. I'd say it's using the on-disk option.

Comment: Heroku apps usually cannot use sqlite3 databases. Sure about that fact?

Comment: actually no. but my yaml file says it is configured that way. I suppose it would be easy for heroku to override that yaml file when i push to their servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using `heroku db:pull <local_filename>`